# Careers: make public profiles more inviting to employers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

I was just in the process of emailing a recruitment related person and I grabbed a link to my public profile which starts off like this:

[image: A picture of some awesome guy's CV]

What's wrong with this? Well, it struck me that the person at the other end might not know where to go from there. In my mind the most obvious thing missing now I've found this nice profile here is *how do I hire this guy?* and *wow, this guy does not know enough jquery, but I'd sure like to search for people who breathe $ symbols as these profiles look awesomesauce*.

So: [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) it is:

- Please add a button with text inviting employers to go to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer` from all public profiles. Yeah, I know, the careers 2.0 image goes to `/`, but it's not obvious or UI-friendly for the potential audience (who may not be at all technical).
- Please add a button saying "How to hire" if they're not logged in, taking them to a page that advertises your service.

These are only suggestions and I'd be more than happy to see some equivalent idea implemented, possibly involving one, two or many different buttons.

Now, as you know, meta specialises in mockups done with mspaint (disclaimer: may not have been done in paint). Here is one to help you visualise this:

[image: Freehand buttons version in two unique colours!]

**tl;dr**: Recruiters, HR staff etc are not technical people. It needs to be easy for them to go from CV to hiring, or they'll give up. And you want them to spend their dollars/stirling/currency on your site. And I want them to, too, so they might hire me.

Comment: As far as I understand, the public profile is for you to show around to other potential employers who may not be on Careers. The changes you propose will make the profile a sales tool for SO not for you, which will defeat its purpose.